# how to disjoin a datacenter from two consul datacenter wan

Tags: consul

I have a cluster of consul servers in two datacenters. each datacenter consists of 3 servers each. When I execute consul members -wan command I can see all 6 servers.

I want to separate these two into individual clusters and no connection between them.
I tried to use the command `force-leave` and `leave` as per the consul documentation:

- https://www.consul.io/commands/force-leave: When I used this command
  the result was a `500 - no node is found`. I tried using the node name as `server.datacenter`, `full FQDN of the server`, `IP of the server`, none of them worked for me.
- https://www.consul.io/commands/leave: When I used this command from
  the node which I want to remove from the cluster, the response was
  success but when I execute `consul members -wan` I still can see this
  node.
  I tried another approach where in I stopped the consul on the node I want to remove from cluster. Then executed the command: `consul force-leave node-name`. Then the command: `consul members -wan` showed this node as `left`. When I started the consul on this node, the node is back in cluster.

What steps am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem I had. I followed the instructions here:
https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500011413401-Remove-WAN-federation-between-Consul-clusters